# Can't add footer to page. Uncaught TypeError

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add a footer to a page, and I'm running into some problems:

> Uncaught TypeError: b.applyTagAndContextClassFor is not a function

This is how my view looks like.

**App.view.xml**

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="com.xyz.controller.App"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App class="myCustomStyle">
    <Page title="{i18n>pageTitle}">
      <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.xyz.view.FirstPanel"/>
      <footer>
        <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.xyz.view.Footer"/>
      </footer>
    </Page>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

**Footer.view.xml**

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="com.xyz.controller.Footer"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
>
  <Toolbar>
    <ToolbarSpacer/>
    <Button type="Accept" text="Accept"/>
    <Button type="Reject" text="Reject"/>
  </Toolbar>
</mvc:View>
```

If I edit App.view.xml to look like this:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
  <mvc:XMLView viewName="com.xyz.view.FirstPanel"/>
  <footer>
    <Toolbar>
      <ToolbarSpacer/>
      <Button type="Accept" text="Accept"/>
      <Button type="Reject" text="Reject"/>
    </Toolbar>
  </footer>
<!-- ... -->
```

Everything works as intended?

Comment: Your error message is from JavaScript. Somewhere in your code you are trying to call `applyTagAndContextClassFor` on an object named `b`. The xml you posted won't have anything to do with the problem or the solution.

Comment: I believe you have to use fragment instead of XMLView

Comment: @I.B.N. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Explanation: The outer most element of your Footer View was a sap.ui.core.mvc.View. The aggregation footer only allows sap.m.IBar. Thus a fragment fixed your error.

Comment: @stacks If you've found the solution, please add it as an answer (with reasons why it didn't work and why it works now) and accept it instead of editing the question. This also helps future readers to find a possible solution quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from XMLView to a Fragment like @I.B.N. suggested ended up fixing the problem.

@Marc explains, "The outermost element of the Footer view was a sap.ui.core.mvc.View. The aggregation footer only allows sap.m.IBar. Changing to a fragment fixed the error."

Corrections:

**App.view.xml**

```
<!-- ... -->
<footer>
    <core:Fragment fragmentName="com.xyz.view.Footer" type="XML"/>
</footer>
<!-- ... -->
```

**Footer.fragment.xml**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
>
    <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <Button type="Accept" text="Accept"/>
        <Button type="Reject" text="Reject"/>
    </Toolbar>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```